# Unable to install MySQL using installer. Get error "unable to determine the products that correspond with that setup type"

Tags: php, mysql, installation

Beginner here.

I'm getting this message.

> unable to determine the products that correspond with that setup type

I get the above error when trying to install MySQl, this occurs on the

> "choosing a setup Type"

screen on the mysql installer. I click on "Developer Default" but when i click next i get the above error. I should note that i have wamp installed and i was thinking that, that might be interfering somehow. I can still go all the way through the installer but nothing installs or shows up on the following pages. Solutions, is there a work around based around wamp? I was not able to find anything or maybe i just wasn't searching the right terms.

Running on a windows 7 machine 64-bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose `Custom` install and choose product that you want to install.

It work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a catalog error in the most recent version of MySQL. An update has been published.

1. Open the MySQL installer.
2. Click on the **Catalog button** (lower right of the installer window)
3. Perform the upgrade.

After this you can click on the **Add** button from the installer window and perform any of the installation options available based on the pre-requisites installed on your system.